# Can developer have access to limited S3 console

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

A developer of mine wants to be able to see the entire contents of the S3 bucket that I've given him to develop with. It seems the only way to do this is to give a limited version of the AWS console to see as objects enter the bucket.

Is this even possible? Is there any other way to allow him to see as objects populate the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IAM roles to control access to resources at a granular level, even down to individual object contained in an S3 bucket.

You can read more about IAM here https://aws.amazon.com/iam/